# Dynamics CRM 2011 On-Premise & Security Certifications (ISO 27001, SAS70, etc)

Tags: security, audit, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I'm unclear on how to properly word our security status. The data center our hosted IFD CRM instance is running on has not paid for these audits. However, the Microsoft literature suggests that CRM Online (which is hosted on MS servers) has these certifications and the certifications are growing with each service update.

If our CRM on-premise software is up-to-date, is it safe to say that the CRM on-premise software itself meets the standards outlined in [here](http://crmpublish.blob.core.windows.net/docs/ReleasePreviewGuide.pdf), but the data center has not been "certified" by an auditor?

- ISO 27001
- SAS70 Type II
- Sarbanes–Oxley
- Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online Service Safe Harbor
- ISO 27001
- SSAE 16 SOC1 (Type II)
- Data Processing Agreement (DPA)
- EU Model Clauses
- Business Associates Agreement - enables a company to be  Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act (HIPAA) compliant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky question that's not always taken for granted by many vendors (sometimes at their own peril).

Many of the audits listed are validation against management practices and controls.  Specifically, ISO 27001, SAS70/SSAE16, SOX 404, and HIPAA are more controls based than technology based (i.e. FIPS 140-2, CC EAL, ICSA Labs product certifications).  Fundamentally, when you take a piece of software and move it to another environment, you'd have to have the entire environment re-audited to be able to assert that you have controls in place and that you practice management according to acceptable practices.

With that said, I'd suggest you consult with an attorney/accredited auditor to determine what claim you can make relative to the standards.  I say "accredited auditor" because many of the compliance programs require auditors maintain specific qualifications (i.e. ISO auditors have to be "Accredited Registrars," SOX auditors are often accounting firms).